# Vim-LaTeX runs evince instead of xdvi

Tags: vim, latex

I have installed the [Vim-LaTeX](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/) plugin, which is great for editing LaTeX documents in Vim. However, I have one problem with viewing the output file.

The [tutorial](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite-quickstart/lsq-viewing-dvi.html) says to use the `\lv` command. However, when I try that, it tries to open `foo.dvi` with `evince`, which happens to fail spectacularly:

[image: evince failure]

This is strange, though, since [the docs say](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/customizing-viewing.html#Tex_ViewRule_format) that `xdvi` should be the default DVI viewer in the first place. Anyway, I tried setting it as the default:

```
:let g:Tex_ViewRule_dvi = 'xdvi'
```

This had absolutely no effect. When I tried

```
:!xdvi foo.dvi
```

it worked perfectly, but I would prefer the easier `\lv` shortcut instead.

How can I solve this problem? I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with Vim 7.4.

Comment: What happens if you double-click a `.dvi` file in nautilus? Maybe the MIME associations are messed up... (just a shot in the dark, I use LaTeX-Box and not Vim-LaTeX so I can't check).

Comment: @Rmano Spot on - I changed the association with `mimeopen` and that fixed it. Thanks! (you can add that as an answer, so I can accept it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Vim-LaTeX is using the standard MIME database for opening the `.dvi` file, the problem could be that the default association is wrong. I have a couple of system where `.dvi` files where associated with evince that is not able to open them.

You can check which application is the default one for opening a file with, for example, Ubuntu Tweak, in Admin->File Type Manager:

[image]

And adding `xdvi` if it is missing:

[image]

Or using the command-line `mimeopen`:

```
[romano:~/tmp] 130 % mimeopen test.dvi   
Please choose a default application for files of type application/x-dvi

    1) Print Preview  (evince-previewer)
    2) Document Viewer  (evince)
    3) Other...

use application #3
use command: xdvi
Opening "test.dvi" with xdvi  (application/x-dvi)
```

which will change the default too.